# Is there a SNMP for trunk ports on Foundry(Brocade) switch?

Tags: snmp

On cisco devices, you can query the SNMP oid `1.3.6.1.4.1.9.5.1.9.3.1.8` 
to check if the interface is a trunk port or not.

Is there a SNMP oid for Foundry (Brocade) switches for the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

SNMP oids are organized in a tree, each number represent a branch option. After the prefix 1.3.6.1.4.1 all the vendors are linked in (All cisco related SNMP information are reachable via 1.3.6.1.4.1.9, since 9 is the id of Cisco as a vendor).

According to [IANA](http://www.iana.org/assignments/enterprise-numbers) Foundry/Brocade has the vendor id 1991.
So my first step would be to check what a [snmpwalk](http://www.net-snmp.org/docs/man/snmpwalk.html) over the oid 1.3.6.1.4.1.1991 returns.

Or you could try and find your device at the [mibDepot](http://www.mibdepot.com/index.shtml).